# Nodejs y htaccess

Tags: nodejs, .htaccess

Tengo este servidor:

```
 const http = require('http');
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');
const port = 3300;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
express()
  .get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
  });
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hola mundo!\n');
});
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${ port }:` + dateFormat(Date.now(),
"dd/mm/yyyy,HH:MM:ss"))
});
```

Alojado en un VPS con ubuntu en la carpeta public_html y este .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^3300$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:3300/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Notificaciones.js [L]
```

pero la página sale 404 al cargarlo.
No sé si el error está en el .htaccess o algún error en la configuración de ubuntu

Gracias!!!